# syscall accept4() returns an invalid value

Tags: linux, system-calls, ptrace

I created a program similar to "strace" which is able to log the syscalls.
Also I installed a webserver and watched the syscalls from 'strace' and from my program and compared them.
For each program, I initiated to the webserver a simple HTTP GET request which created several syscalls.

#### In my program:

I noticed that in a certain accept4() execution, the return value is (-11), meaning (minus 11) !
But that (-11) return value for accept4() should never happen.
I can't figure out why I get (-11) in register RAX when the accept4() syscall exits.

[Attached the log](https://pastebin.com/fuLY52Fq) of my program.
There are two accept4() syscalls (syscall number 288):

- Line 14: First accept4() syscall, entry.
- Line 18: First accept4() syscall, exit.
- Line 86: Second accept4() syscall, entry.
- Line 90: Second accept4() syscall, exit.

#### In the 'strace' program:

The suspected accept4() returns (-1) which 'strace' identifies as EAGAIN.
But according to 'errno' program, then:

```
~$ errno 1
EPERM 1 Operation not permitted
~$ errno 11
EAGAIN 11 Resource temporarily unavailable
```

[Attached the log](https://pastebin.com/wTBtRuKF) of the 'strace' program.
There are two accept4() syscalls (syscall number 288):

- Line 4: First accept4() syscall.
- Line 15: Second accept4() syscall.

### My questions are:

1. Why strace reports a different return value than my program?
2. How should I properly interpret the (-11) that the second accept4() syscall returns?

---

Additional technical data:

Using gcc compiler with flags "-g -Wall" and linker flag "-lm".

The important data from "gcc -v" is:

```
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
gcc version 11.3.0 (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04)
```

Include paths from "cpp -v":

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/include
/usr/local/include
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/include
```

Answer (score 0):

`strace` seems to show all error returns as -1 along with the error code:

```
$ strace ls /enoent
...
stat("/enoent", 0x55c15dfbb150)         = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

That's what the system call wrapper functions return anyway, so it's not exactly wrong, even though the kernel returns just one value. (Though looking at the tables in the `syscall(2)` man page, there's variation between architectures on how the return values and errors are returned from the kernel.)

Showing the values according to the user space interface might just be a usability choice, but I don't know.